# Trying to log in to web page from Excel VBA but username and password grayed out

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate logging in to a web page using VBA code in Excel. I can set the username value and password value, but it appears greyed out and the web page doesn't seem to recognise it. When I send the click event to the login button it says I haven't input the username and password. I've tried setting the focus to the username and password fields first, but no success.

```
Sub test_login()
    Set obj_Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_count = obj_Shell.Windows.count
    On Error Resume Next
    For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
        my_url = obj_Shell.Windows(x).Document.Location
        ' actual url=http://community.betfair.com
        If my_url Like "*community*" Then
            Set ie = obj_Shell.Windows(x)
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set username_box = ie.Document.getelementbyid("username")
    username_box.Value = "myusername"
    Set password_box = ie.Document.getelementbyid("passwordText")
    password_box.Value = "mypassword"
    Set login_button = ie.Document.getelementbyid("login")
    login_button.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you open to a selenium basic vba answer?

Comment: I'd suspect there is some javascript code that checks for automated logins and disables those efforts.

Comment: My solution works fine for me. So, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is expecting text entry via keystrokes which means the dreaded SendKeys is I think required. The following works:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://community.betfair.com/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document

            With .getElementById("username")
                .Focus
                SendKeys "Bob"
            End With

            SendKeys "{tab}"

            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

            With .getElementById("passwordText")
                .Focus
                SendKeys "Banana"
            End With

            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

            .getElementById("login").Click

            While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Stop '<==Delete me later

        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for replying QHarr but I can't get your code to work. The username and password boxes aren't getting filled.

Comment: Try with longer wait e.g. Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)

Comment: Can you post the URL of the page, We will try to make a test with it to produce the issue.

Comment: Did you try with longer waits John?

Comment: Yes - I stepped through the code in debug mode and waited for 10 seconds between each step. I can get the username to appear if I set the value after the sendkeys statement, but the same trick doesn't seem to work for the password. There are 2 ids for password - "password" and "passwordText". Don't know if that has something to do with it?

Comment: Nope. Don't F8. Please use the code as written above and add longer waits e.g. change the Wait lines to  Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) then run with F8 and just let the code run.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks I just tried it and it worked with the longer waits. Thanks!.

Comment: No worries. Not as robust as we might hope for but progress :-)